# Accessing a chunk of memory by pointer in C from a big.matrix in R

Tags: c++, c, r, rcpp, r-bigmemory

The `bigmemory` package in R provides a class, `big.matrix` which stores a matrix in memory that can be shared across R sessions as some sort of `C++` object, returning a pointer to the `R` language.

For example:

```
library(bigmemory)
> a <- as.big.matrix(matrix(0, 5, 5))
> a
An object of class "big.matrix"
Slot "address":
<pointer: 0x24ae350>
```

Using more functions from the `bigmemory` package i can then write out a short description of the matrix to file, open up another R session, and access the matrix in memory from that new R session.

From `R` you can also call `C`/`C++` code using the `.Call()` or `.C()`.

I would like to implement some functions in either `C` or `C++` (I am more familiar with `C`) that will run on this matrix in shared memory, but I have no idea how to go about this.

Given an address in memory, along with known sizes can I access an double[][] in `C`? or am I completely off track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok luckiliy for you Dirk Eddelbuettel and Romain Francois wrote an awesome tool called [Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html) that will do all the (very) hard work for you.
Install the package, read the vignettes et enjoy reusing all the example code available on [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/)

There is even an example of how to use `bigmemory` in conjunction with `Rcpp` [here](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-bigmemory-with-rcpp/)

Comment: Answer might be improved (as am learning myself) if you could be a little more specific about an example/general use case, particularly regarding use of pointers/address location.

Comment: I added a link to example with bigmemory, and there is really plainty of example over SO, just google/Rseek Rcpp, there is also a book written on the subject

Comment: Thanks and no worries, I'm waiting for mine to arrive!

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I need!